# NuxtJS Dynamic Routes SSR

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

SSR isn't working with Dynamic Routes (_id.vue file) in **NuxtJS**, I'm using **asyncData** function to render on server side the dynamic values from database, it's working in dev mode but after generate static project nothing is render is Server side, including HTML tags with static value.

_id.vue

```html
<template>
  <v-app>
            <h3 class="typo-title3">Localização</h3>
            <p
              class="address"
            >{{data.nome | capitalize}} está localizado no bairro {{data.bairro | capitalize}}, {{data.rua | capitalize}}, {{data.num}}, na cidade de {{data.cidade | capitalize}}.</p>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import fsAct from "@/functions/fsAct";
import firebase from "~/assets/js/firebase";

export default {
  mixins: [fsAct],
  data() {
    return {
      id: this.$route.params.id,
      data: {
        fachada: ""
      }
    };
  },
  /* SSR */
  async asyncData({ route, params }) {
    const ref = firebase
      .firestore()
      .collection("example")
      .doc(params.id);
    let snap;
    try {
      snap = await ref.get();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    const prefix =
      "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/easyhouse-am.appspot.com/o/";
    let dados = snap.data();
    dados.fachada = prefix + dados.fachada.replace("/", "%2F") + "?alt=media";
    return {
      data: dados
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.fsSelectOne("example", this.id).then(res => {
      this.data = res.data();
    });
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Have you solved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing `nuxt generate` then it is going to build the static pages without server. So you don't even have a server to call the async data method.

This will be called on the client side when the page is visited.

You should make use of lifecycle method `beforeCreate` if you are only building static website.

Comment: `beforeCreate` is not working in case you use mixins where you have your bunch of functions fetching the data from backend